# How do I use Github to create a totally separate project from a previous project?

Tags: xcode, version-control, github

I have a project on github that my developer and I used to collaborate on an iPhone app. That was my first exposure to version control and I used only a few tasks/commands: push, pull, stash on occasion.

We're now looking into making an OS X version and I'd like to use that previous project as the starting point for this new project.

It seems like this is FORKING the project. But I want to make sure that, once copied, the new (OS X) project has nothing to do with the previous (iOS) project. Is that what forking does? I've usually only heard it in regards to adding features. I've also heard the term cloning, but I believe that refers to making the local copy?

Comment: Why do you that? And what do you mean by having nothing to do with the previous project? Not even sharing history?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Create a blank new project on GitHub
2. Do a git clone on the latest version of the iOS project to make a new copy of it.
3. Edit the information in the git config under .git in the copy folder to point to the new project on GitHub.

Comment: You don't even need to mess with .git... `git remote set-url origin new_url`

Answer (score 1):

Forking is what you want. Creating a new project will lose the history from the original project, and will make it considerably more difficult to merge changes back and forth between the two. (Which you're likely to end up wanting to do if the projects are related *at all*.)

Comment: It doesn't sound like he wants a fork, he wants an entirely new repo that just shares the same code as a current one.

Comment: That's what a fork is! There's no requirement that forks ever be merged back together.